# Laravel 5.3 : redirected you too many times error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am experiencing this error when trying to navigate to "/admin". Other routes such as "/employee" are working fine.

Here are my current web routes

```
Auth::routes();

/* Voyager Routes */
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
Voyager::routes();
...
});

/* Badge App Routes - All the dashboard routes for managers, employees and HRs are defined here */
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'employee'], function () {
  Route::get('/', 'frontend\DashboardController@index')->name('homepage');
  Route::get('dashboard', 'frontend\DashboardController@index')->name('homepage');
  ...
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
  Route::resource('team-manager', 'frontend\TeamManagerController');

  Route::resource('badges', 'backend\BadgeController');
  Route::get('badges/award/{id?}', 'backend\BadgeController@award');
  Route::post('store_award', 'backend\BadgeController@storeAward')->name('store_award');
});

/* User Redirector - Based on user role */
Route::group(['middleware' => ['redirector']], function () {
    Route::get('/');
    Route::get('login');
});
```

And here's my middleware redirector

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
    if (!Auth::guest()) {
        $user = User::find(Auth::id());
        // TODO: fix static id below
        return $user->role_id == 1 ? redirect('admin') : redirect('employee');
    }
    return redirect(route('voyager.login'));
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want too handle role base access control, I suggest you to use this package. https://github.com/DynamicCodeNinja/RBAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your middleware:

```
return $user->role_id == 1 ? redirect('admin') : redirect('employee');
```

You have admin role, and you are also in `/admin` page. Then your middleware redirects you again and again to `/admin`.

It is better to check if the user is not in the `/admin` or `/admin/*` related routes, then redirect him to admin.

```
if($user->role_id == 1) {

    //check if user is in /admin or /admin related routes.
    return ($request->is('/admin') or $request->is('/admin/*')) ? $next($request) : redirect('admin');

} else {
    redirect('/employee');
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help. but unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I'll try to implement the role base access control that you suggested above and remove the Voyager package that currently doesn't work. thanks!

Comment: I already used that package in my last three projects. It works great and no bug at all! Maybe you missed something. Please share what your problem is.

Comment: That's great! . My problem with redirects still exists even if I remove the route code for middleware redirector. The weird part is in my old project folder where this project was first installed, routes are working fine having the same codes. The problem only appears for newly cloned projects.

Comment: So, Maybe something is wrong with the Voyager::routes(). It is better to search through its github issues page.